# Choose Multiple Columns in Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dataset of jobs for a gardening company with 50 or so columns.

```
status   #    ID     Date       Name   Frequency    Height   Weight   DOB...
☐        4    340    09/06/20   Jack   Once Off     175      100      11/1/60...
☐        1    543    22/05/20   Sarah  Weekly       170      201      12/2/87...
☐        3    121    01/05/20   Emily  Fortnightly  172      150      6/6/90...
☐        3    577    11/06/20   Peter  Once Off     165      165      31/1/89...
```

I have a custom script that recreates a new row when the checkbox is selected for weekly and fortnightly jobs and increases the # field by 1 and adds the appropriate date in the future for the date field. I also want it to copy all other data in the original row into the new row.

Currently it will copy up to column 9 but I have 50 columns that need the original data copied over. Is it possible to use more efficient code rather than using the below 50 times?

```
sheet.getRange(selectedRow,5).getValue(),
sheet.getRange(selectedRow,6).getValue(),
sheet.getRange(selectedRow,7).getValue(),
sheet.getRange(selectedRow,8).getValue(),
sheet.getRange(selectedRow,9).getValue(),
```

Here is the script:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var checkbox = sheet.getActiveRange().getValue();
  var selectedRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var selectedFreq = sheet.getRange(selectedRow, 6).getValue();
  
  //Run if selected cell has a checkbox and ticked
  while(checkbox == true){ 
    addValues(selectedRow, sheet, selectedFreq);
    break;
  }
}

//Function to process values based on frequency
function addValues(selectedRow, sheet, selectedFreq){ 
  var number = sheet.getRange(selectedRow,2).getValue();
  var date = new Date(sheet.getRange(selectedRow,4).getValue());

  if(selectedFreq == "Fortnightly"){
    //Insert a new row after the ticked checkbox, setup a new date with 14 days (or 2 weeks), increments the # with 1 & the rest of the data are copied
    var newDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()+14));
    sheet.appendRow(["",number+1,sheet.getRange(selectedRow,3).getValue(),newDate,
    sheet.getRange(selectedRow,5).getValue(),
    sheet.getRange(selectedRow,6).getValue(),
    sheet.getRange(selectedRow,7).getValue(),
    sheet.getRange(selectedRow,8).getValue(),
    sheet.getRange(selectedRow,9).getValue()]);
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1).insertCheckboxes();
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),4).setValue(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),4).getValue()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yy");
  }

  if(selectedFreq == "Weekly"){
    //Insert a new row after the ticked checkbox, setup a new date with 7 days (1 week), increments the # with 1 & the rest of the data are copied
    var newDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()+7));
    sheet.appendRow(["",number+1,sheet.getRange(selectedRow,3).getValue(),newDate,
    sheet.getRange(selectedRow,5).getValue(),
    sheet.getRange(selectedRow,6).getValue(),
    sheet.getRange(selectedRow,7).getValue(),
    sheet.getRange(selectedRow,8).getValue(),
    sheet.getRange(selectedRow,9).getValue()]);
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1).insertCheckboxes();
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),4).setValue(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),4).getValue()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yy");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use [Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) and [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) to get the row values with multiple columns.

**Sample:**

```
var values = sheet.getRange(selectedRow,1,1,50).getValues();
values[0][1] = number+1;
sheet.appendRow(values.flat());
```

- With this, you can get the values of your selected row, from column 1 to column 50.
- Then you can just update specific index in your array `values` depending on your preference. Like `values[0][1] = number+1`
- Lastly, you can use your array `values` in `Sheet.appendRow()`. You can use `array.flat()` to convert 2-d array to 1-d array

### (UPDATE)

**Your code must be something like this:**

```
//Function to process values based on frequency
function addValues(selectedRow, sheet, selectedFreq){ 

  var rowValues = sheet.getRange(selectedRow,1,1,50).getValues().flat();  
  var date = new Date(sheet.getRange(selectedRow,4).getValue());

  if(selectedFreq == "Fortnightly"){
    //Insert a new row after the ticked checkbox, setup a new date with 14 days (or 2 weeks), increments the # with 1 & the rest of the data are copied
    var newDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()+14));

    //Update column A,B and D
    rowValues[0] = "";
    rowValues[1] += 1;
    rowValues[3] = newDate;
    sheet.appendRow(rowValues);
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1).insertCheckboxes();
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),4).setValue(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),4).getValue()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yy");
  }
  
}
```

- I get the selected row values from column 1 to 50. Then use array.flat() to change the result from 2-d array to 1-d array
- I changed column A, B and D based on your original code
- appended the updated data in the sheet

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered an issue implementing this.

Comment: Would you be able to put this into my script if possible? I'm having trouble making it work!

Comment: can you share a sample sheet? with an expected output?

Comment: Can you check the updated answer if that will work? I  was not able to run that code since I don't have an example input